# Google Web App Permissions

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a simple Script deployed as a Web App.  What I'm looking to do is for the URL to include a single parameter which returns a value from a Google Document Spreadsheet.  It all works when signed on as me.

What I want is anyone to be able to use this.  I thought that Execute the app as: me and Who has access to the app: Anyone, even anonymous would be what I want.

However, it always puts up a Google login screen and after that starts asking for permissions on the App and the Google document.

Am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK ... I *think* I've solved it.

I needed to create a new version of the project and then Deploy this one with the final permissions rather than changing the permissions of the existing one.

I hope that helps someone else as I've been banging my head against the door on this one!